# IP Failover - Configured, but disabled

Tags: linux, configuration, failover, ip-address

I have multiple debian servers on which I configured "IP Failovers" or "Floating IPs".

My floating IP is `10.0.0.2` and I have an `A` records: `www.example.com` pointing to this IP.

I configured this floating IP on all my servers with the command:

`ip addr add 10.0.0.2/32 brd 10.0.0.254 dev eth0 label eth0:0`

Now, let's say my IP Failover currently points to `server-1`. We could represent this like this:

```
                                  _  _
                                 ( `   )_
                               (    )    `)
                              (_   (_ .  _) _)
                                    |    
                                    |
                                    |
                            |--------------|
                            |  10.0.0.2    |
                            |--------------|
                               /      
                              /        
                             /          
             |--------------|            |--------------|
             | server-1     |            | server-3     |
             | IP: 10.1.1.1 |            | IP: 10.3.3.3 |  
             | IP: 10.0.0.2 |            | IP: 10.0.0.2 |  
             |--------------|            |--------------|
```

Let's connect to `server-3` and ping `www.example.com`:

```
$ ping www.example.com
PING www.example.com (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.  
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.022 ms 
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.012 ms 
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.013 ms 
^C                                                              
--- www.example.com ping statistics ---                        
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms  
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.012/0.015/0.022/0.006 ms
```

So that's perfect, except 1 detail: the machine answering the ping in the output above is not `server-1`, it's `server-3`

It makes complete sense; `10.0.0.2` is a local address to `server-3`

So here's my question:

**How can I configure 10.0.0.2 on all my servers, yet, "disable" it on servers which the IP Failover is not pointing to?**

Thank you for your help

Comment: Youll get IP address conflicts bring up the address on all 3 servers. Something like http://www.keepalived.org is what you want.

Comment: Let's say I can't use keepalived. Is there a way with the "ip addr" command or something else to "configure" a secondary IP, but tell the system to ignore it until... I run a command to tell the system "stop ginoring it".

Comment: Nope, and anyway how will you tell 1 of the 3 systems to stop ignoring it without making the other two stop ignoring it at the same time? KeepaliveD is meant for this purpose.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. My setup is not complex. There's no reason why the 2 other systems would also start ignoring it.